# How to Get / Update Customer GL Account info via Rest API

Tags: rest, acumatica

I'm trying to figure out how to Get and Update a Customer's GL Accounts info via Rest API.

As seen in this screenshot, a Customer's GL Accounts section has fields such as:

- AR Account
- AR Sub
- Sales Account
- Sales Sub
- etc.

[image]

Via Rest API, where can I retrieve this Customer's above info, and how can I update them accordingly?

I'm able to perform CRUD for all the other Customer entity fields, but I'm quite lost regarding how per Customer GL Accounts can be retrieved and updated. Looking for any help to point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those fields are not the part of the Default endpoint, so you need some tricks to retrieve or update them.

You can either use custom endpoint or retrieve/update these fields using 'Custom' fields collection.

As for custom endpoint, [here](https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c920d9fc-8e81-4f4e-9250-81c6fb979517) is the link that can help.

As for the custom fields, you can retrieve the values like that:

GET: `{{sitename}}/entity/Default/20.200.001/Customer?$custom=DefLocation.CSalesAcctID, DefLocation.CARAccountID`

Response:

```
{
"id": "90f25585-fbc0-eb11-9d4f-3ce1a14ed5bf",
"CustomerID": {
    "value": "AAA"
},

"custom": {
    "DefLocation": {
        "CSalesAcctID": {
            "type": "CustomStringField",
            "value": "40000"
        },
        "CARAccountID": {
            "type": "CustomStringField",
            "value": "11000"
        }
    }
}
}
```

See [here](https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=bd0d8a36-b00b-44c8-bdcd-b2b4e4c86fd0) how to get the field names.

To update the fields you send them in the body the same way you get them in the response

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!